# Are other classes accessing the webdriver instance correctly when extending testbase class? See Java NullPointerException Error

Tags: selenium-webdriver, nullpointerexception, instance, extends, selenium-grid

I am getting this error when running the below selenium scripts using TestNG with Selenium Grid. I'm extending the testbase class to access the WebDriver, but I'm not sure if each class is getting the WebDriver instance correctly since I'm getting a NullPointerException? The tests scrolls to the first item to click and doesn't click it. I'm new to Java, please advise. I am wondering if I'm understanding inheritance and initiation of objects correctly.
Thanks for your help.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code:

```
public class WatchTV {

    WebDriver driver;
    int waitseconds = 60;

    public WatchTV(WebDriver driver){
        this.driver = driver;
    }

    By watchtvlink = By.linkText("Watch TV »");

    public WebElement WatchTVLink()
    {
        WebDriverWait wait =  new WebDriverWait(driver, waitseconds);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(watchtvlink));
        return driver.findElement(watchtvlink);
    }

}
```

The explanation is here: https://sqa.stackexchange.com/a/20199/17159 in your own question